# How to move to the next file in python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

So I am writing an adventure game, and once you have managed to get out of the first room, I want to open up the next "room" which is a second python file. How do I do this? I have tried:

```
import os
os.system("start "+"agroom2.pyw")
```

but this doesn't seem to work. So how *do* you open a different python file, in python?

Comment: If the file is in the same directory, you can `import` its contents and run its methods.

Comment: Check out some python tutorials and especially for `import` because what you're trying to do is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: ps - agroom2._py_ doesn't work nor does anything else. Believe me, I've tried

Comment: Assuming that this is a console-based text game, you want to use `.py` files and not `.pyw`. `.pyw` extension is used for GUI programs that don't use a console window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing rooms is probably the easiest answer. One way to do this is to

- create a directory for your game to live in
- make an empty file called `__init__.py`. This tells python that importable files live in this directory
- run your main script from this directory and import stuff.

Here's a quick example

in dir `ag`:

`__init__.py` (empty)

`start.py`

```
import agroom1
import agroom2

print("The start of the game")

while True:
    choice = input("next? > ")
    if choice == '1':
        agroom1.main()
    if choice == '2':
        agroom2.main()
    if choice == 'quit':
        break;
```

`agroom1.py`

```
def main():
    print("In room 1")
```

`agroom2.py`

```
def main():
    print("In room 2")
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, rather then running the script from outside of python, you should import your game rooms into your main script. You can call functions from other scripts in the same directly using `import`.

```
import room1, room2, room3`

...

if room1.status == 'Complete':
   room2.start

...

if room2.status == 'Complete':
   room3.start
```

Investigate how to use `import` for this purpose here:
[Python Import Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel a bit of a fool. I have worked it out and it is, oh so simple. You literally do:

```
import agroom2
```

As a test I wrote `print("Hi")` and on the file I imported it into `Hi` appeared in the output after all the other output. So there you go!